# Compare multiple SQL table data based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL tables one with sales order date and total for the day. Then I have another table with invoice date and total invoice for the day. On both of these tables there are some dates with no records at all.

I need your help to join these two tables and get sales order total and invoice total against each and every day as you can see in the below image.

[image: My table structure and result that I'm looking for is below]

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that with two aggregate subqueries and a`FULL OUTER JOIN` like :

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(ord.oday, inv.iday) AS date,
    ord.ototal AS order_total,
    inv.itotal AS invoice_total
FROM 
(
    SELECT
        CAST(orderdate AS DATE) AS oday,
        SUM(localvalue) AS ototal,
    FROM dbo.SALESORD_HRD
    GROUP BY CAST(orderdate As DATE)
) AS ord FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        CAST(transdate AS DATE) iday,
        SUM(amount) itotal,
    FROM dbo.DR_TRANS
    WHERE TRANSTYPE = '1'
    GROUP BY CAST(transdate As DATE)
) AS inv
    ON ord.oday = inv.iday
```

Comment: this seems to be working fine when I cross check the result with the total.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the easiest way would be to aggregate the results from a `UNION ALL`

**Example**

```
Select [Date]  = OrderDate
      ,Sales   = sum(Sales)
      ,Invoice = sum(Invoice)
From  (
        Select OrderDate
              ,Sales   = sum(LovalValue)
              ,Invoice = cast(null as money)
         From  SalesOrd_HDR
         Group By OrderDate
        Union All
        Select TransDate
              ,cast(null as money)
              ,sum(Amount)
         From  DR_Trans
         WHERE TRANSTYPE = '1'
         Group By TransDate
      ) A
 Group By OrderDate
```

Comment: Thanks John, but I am getting wrong total value on invoice side when I use this. Can not find the reason why

Comment: @CrysisHhtht Sorry, I missed the WHERE TRANSTYPE = '1'

Comment: @CrysisHhtht Always best to paste you attempts and sample data as text and not images.

Comment: will do that next time John. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.